# CDI 1.1: Is @Observes @Initialized(TransactionScoped.class) supposed to work?

Tags: java, cdi, weld, apache-tomee, openwebbeans

CDI 1.1: Is `@Observes @Initialized(TransactionScoped.class)` supposed to work?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClass {
public void processConversationScopedInit(@Observes 
  @Initialized(TransactionScoped.class) Object payload) {}

  public void processConversationScopedDestroyed(@Observes 
  @Destroyed(TransactionScoped.class) Object payload) {}
}
```

It's a standard scope in CDI 1.1, but it's conspiciuously missing from this list here:

http://www.next-presso.com/2014/06/you-think-you-know-everything-about-cdi-events-think-again/

I can't seem to get it to work in TomEE 7.0.5/OpenWebBeans, and I'm curious if that's just an oversight in the spec. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@TransactionScoped` is *not* a standard scope in a way that it is not implemented by CDI (or, well, CDI impls). It [comes from JTA](https://github.com/javaee/javax.transaction/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/transaction/TransactionScoped.java) and it also has their package - `javax.transaction`.

That being said, it should behave as all other `@NormalScope` contexts and hence should fire the `@Initialized` events for you to observe. Although do note that [CDI spec only recommends this](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#builtin_contexts) by saying:

> Portable extensions are encouraged to fire an event with qualifier @Initialized(X.class) when a custom context is initialized, and an event with qualifier @Destroyed(X.class) when a custom context is destroyed, where X is the scope type associated with the context. A suitable event payload should be chosen.

I haven't tried this myself but I would wager this works for most up to date implementations. Then again, you are in CDI 1.1 which is now pretty ancient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since it is not required and potentially adds a significative overhead which can be avoided using the already provided request scope event then this was not added to tomee.

Issue when you start implementing something from javax.* which is not spec-ed is that users will think it is portable when it is actually wrong so better to respect the spec when possible IMHO.